# After three years, an unanswered question is still on M.SE

Tags: discussion

I've understood that the system removes the unanswered questions after a while, but as far as I can see there are questions like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/44923/grade-of-a-maximal-prime-ideal-in-a-noetherian-ufd?noredirect=1#comment1765574_44923) which are still alive after three years. Could someone explain what's going on?

Comment: Not relevant, but, for what it's worth, there are two answers to that question, each deleted by its author.

Comment: There might be a few more like that. I was quite surprised to find this one: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/79092/how-does-quater-imaginary-and-other-imaginary-complex-bases-work/842288#842288

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[The rules of automatic deletion from Meta SE:](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year/92006#92006)

> **If the question is more than `30` days old, and ...**
>
> - has −1 or lower score
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
>
> **...or...**
>
> - it was closed and migrated to a different site
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted.
>
> **If the question is more than `365` days old, and ...**
>
> - has a score of 0 *or* a score of 1 with a deleted owner
> - has no answers
> - is not locked
> - has a viewcount <= the age of the question in days times 1.5
> - has 1 or 0 comments
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted.
>
> These checks are run every week across all sites.

This specific question is not deleted as it has a score higher than 0 and too many comments to qualify.